# How to prevent that an Java Update on Windows delete the Java preferences?

Tags: java, windows, updates, preferences

An update of the Java 32 bit Java delete all Java Preferences of the 64 bit Java. The typical use case is that a server applications has a 64 bit bundled Java VM. If you now update the 32 bit Java which is used for browser and desktop apps this delete all settings of the server applications which are saved in the Java Preferences.

Related bugs are:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8135254
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146305

Is there a workaround to prevent this delete of Java Preferences?